# How do I show that $f$ is $\frac{1}{4}$ Lipschitz continuous with this metric: $\delta(x,y)= |\frac{1}{\pi -x} - \frac{1}{\pi -y}| + |x-y|$

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, lipschitz-functions

> Let $f: \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that: $$x \mapsto \left\{\begin{matrix}
> 1 & \text{if } x > \pi\\ 
> 0 & \text{if } x < \pi
> \end{matrix}\right.$$
>   Show that $f$ is continuous in the usual metrics. Then show that if we use the metric: $\delta: \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ such that: $$(x,y )\mapsto |\frac{1}{\pi -x} - \frac{1}{\pi -y}| + |x-y| $$ then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with the Lipschitz contant equal to $\frac{1}{4}$.

So in order to show that $f$ is continuous, here was my approach:

Let $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, suppose that $x < \pi$. Let $\epsilon > 0$, then let's put $\eta = \frac{|x - \pi|}{2}$, then $\forall y \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x-y| < \eta$, we necessarily have $y < \pi$, thus $f(x)=f(y)$ and so $|f(x)-f(y)|=0<\epsilon$. In similar fashion I would reason for $x > \pi$.

Now in order to show that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous with Lipschitz constant equal to $\frac{1}{4}$, I would need to show that $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \frac{1}{4} \delta(x,y)$.
Now this is obvious if  $x,y > \pi$ or $x,y < \pi$ because then $f(x)=f(y)$, thus $|f(x)-f(y)|=0$. The issue I get is when I try to show that for $x<\pi<y$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \frac{1}{4}\delta(x,y)$.

We have $f(x)=0$ and $f(y) = 1$, thus $|f(x)-f(y)|=1$, but I don't see how $1 \leq \frac{1}{4}(|\frac{1}{\pi -x} - \frac{1}{\pi -y}| + |x-y|) $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x < π < y$,\begin{align*}
δ(x, y) &= \left|\frac{1}{π - x} + \frac{1}{y - π}\right| + |y - x| = \frac{1}{π - x} + \frac{1}{y - π} + y - x\\
&= (y - π) + \frac{1}{y - π} + (π - x) + \frac{1}{π - x} \geqslant 2 + 2 = 4 = 4|f(x) - f(y)|,
\end{align*}
so$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \leqslant \frac{1}{4} δ(x, y).
$$

Comment: Actually the $\leqslant$ is a strict one, since $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: How do you show that $(y-\pi)+ \frac{1}{y- \pi} \geq 2$? Might be obvious, but I am unable to see right now why this is necessarily the case.

Comment: @JohnMayne using the the AM–GM inequality.

Comment: Because $x+1/x \ge 2$ for $x > 0$.  $x+1/x-2=(\sqrt{x}-1/\sqrt{x})^2$.